# oxyplot bars are out of order,sequential problems

Tags: oxyplot

using Oxyplot to plot candlesticks , key codes as follow:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
_timeSpanAxis.Minimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(0));
_timeSpanAxis.Maximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(600));
var startime = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(300));

items.Add(new HighLowItem(startime, 1.58334, 0.58134, 1.18199, 1.38256));
plotview.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

this figure can be plotted normallly.

but when i add another item, it cause exception: bars are out of order.
codes as follow:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
_timeSpanAxis.Minimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(0));
_timeSpanAxis.Maximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(600));
var startime = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(300));

items.Add(new HighLowItem(startime, 1.58334, 0.58134, 1.18199, 1.38256));
startime = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(date.AddSeconds(400));
items.Add(new HighLowItem(startime, 1.58334, 0.58134, 1.18199, 1.38256));
plotview.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

i cannot figure out what's wrong here? has anybody ever encountered with  such problem?